# Why two folders for MS Office installation

Tags: windows-7, installation, microsoft-office, microsoft-access

I recently bumped into a major issue with my MS Office 2007 installation regarding Access 2007, which gave me an error that it could not properly reference ActiveX Data Objects 6.1.

While trying to solve the problem, I found that the Office installation has two very similar folders:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\`
- `C:\Program Files      \Common Files\System\ado\`

Both folders have very similar content but all files are of slightly different size. This is where many of the Access reference ActiveX Data Objects are stored.

I found that by default my Access Reference navigator is leading me into the `(x86)` folder and the other folder is **not** available for me to navigate and choose the actual desired DLL file.

I also found that Microsoft has never published a 64bits version of Office (I doubt that information), which I think means that it would make sense that all files would be in the `(x86)` folder.

Why would there be two different folders with pretty much the same file names (of different size) (which imply that same name files are of different codes)?

Does this mean that there are two different versions of ActiveX Data Objects 6.1?

Could that mean that my problem was that I could not reference the proper file version?

---

PS: I finally had to fix the bug by running the Repair command from the installation CD.

Comment: It is not true that "Microsoft has never published a 64-bit version of Office". In fact, every version of Office since 2007 has been available in 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft provides a 32-bit version and a 64-bit version of the ActiveX Data Components. That way, software developers can make 32-bit and 64-bit programs that use them. The reason they are different sizes is because 32-bit and 64-bit memory pointers are different sizes. (Usually, this would mean that the 64-bit versions would be larger, but that is not always the case, because 64-bit processors also have a lot of optimizations to make certain types of code run using simpler binary/assembly code.)

Your assumption that these components were installed along with Office is incorrect. ADO is part of the "Microsoft Data Access Components" (MDAC) package, which is actually a part of the Operating System. That is why the version number, 6.1, matches the Windows version number for Windows 7, which is also 6.1.

The reason that your version of Microsoft Access is leading you to the `(x86)` folder is because it is the 32-bit version of Access so it can only use the 32-bit components. If you had the 64-bit version of Access (which, contrary to your assertion in the question, does actually exist), you would only be able to view the components in the non-`(x86)` directory.

(The fact that you were able to fix your original problem by running a Windows Repair means that you had problems with your Windows installation, or possibly a corruption in a Windows Update while it was being installed. However, that has absolutely nothing to do with the presence of these two folders.)